# How to refactor two similar methods in one

Tags: java, refactoring

There is one method. In one case I need to return variable with one type. In another case I need  to return variable with another type. I created two methods. But I know that it is not a good idea because of duplication of code. How do I fix it and use one method?

```
public ClassA doSomething(String aString, String bString, String cString, String dString) {
    ClassA client;
    ClientFactory clientFactory = new ClientFactoryImpl();
    client = clientFactory.createNewClient(aString, bString);
    ClassB conn = clientFactory.connect(cString, dString);
    return client;
}

public ClassB doSomething(String aString, String bString, String cString, String dString) {
    ClassA client;
    ClientFactory clientFactory = new ClientFactoryImpl();
    client = clientFactory.createNewClient(aString, bString);
    ClassB conn = clientFactory.connect(cString, dString);
    return conn;
}
```

Comment: What duplication of code? Instantiating a class? Please provide a better example.

Comment: This example is not sufficient to show an issue. Maybe show something a bit more complete.

Comment: The body of methods are the same instead of return and the parameters are the same

Comment: First of all, your codes won't even compile. Method overloading  does not consider return type.

Comment: Why do you create `ClassB conn = new ClassB();` in the first methid and ` ClassA client = new ClassA();` in the second?

Comment: The method make the same things. But in one case I need to return ClassA client. In another case I need to return ClassB conn

Comment: There must be something wrong with your implementation when you face a problem like this. You probably will want to show a more specific scenario when you need to use the first method, and when to use the other.

Comment: Your first method instantiates a `ClassB` without doing anything with it. Your second method instantiates a `ClassA` without doing anything with it. Overlooking the compile error, this can be reduced to `ClassA doSomething(...) {return new ClassA();}` and `ClassB doSomething(...) {return new ClassB();}`.

Comment: Sorry. I modified the code

Comment: I think you want to use a Tuple2 - or Pair object. You are instantiating both objects ClassA and ClassB each time. You can just have a single method that returns both new Pair<>(client,conn);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general case, when client and conn depend on each other:

```
class SomethingResult {
  ClassA client;
  ClassB conn;
  SomethingResult(ClassA client, ClassB conn) {
    this.client = client;
    this.conn = conn;
  }
  // Getters
}

public SomethingResult doSomething(String aString, String bString, String cString, String dString) {
    // Create client and conn and execute any other logic
    return new SomethingResult(client, conn);
}
```

Then, for example, to get client:

```
ClassA client = doSomething(aString, bString, cString, dString).getClient();
```

In your specific case there is no need for this; you can simply do:

```
public ClassA getClient(String aString, String bString) {
    ClientFactory clientFactory = new ClientFactoryImpl();
    return clientFactory.createNewClient(aString, bString);
}

public ClassB getConn(String cString, String dString) {
    ClientFactory clientFactory = new ClientFactoryImpl();
    return clientFactory.connect(cString, dString);
}
```

Comment: @user2995987 Why are you not doing like what was stated here with `getClient()` and `getConn()`? It makes much more sense than using one method to do 2 different things together.

Comment: Dragan Bozanovic, thanks a lot. it was realy helpfull and now I am happy. Thanks